# How we can redirect static content request to external static server using jersey/jax.ws.rs ContainerRequestFilter in spring boot application

Tags: java, filter, jersey, spring-boot-starter

suppose we have a springboot application with UI code deployed in a internal server called internalserver1
.
when UI are requesting  image with relative URL /asset/image/imagename.jpg , then the server appending the internal server host name and making the URL like http://internalserver1:8080/asset/image/imagename.jpg  when we are storing the image in a external server which is out side of the deployed application, how we redirect to external static content server using jersey ContainerRequestFilter?

so the request should redirect from http://internalserver1:8080/asset/images/imagename.jps to  http://externalserver:8089/asset/images/imagename.jpg.
I tried to use the below snippet but its not working.

```
request.getDespatcher("http://externalserver:8089"+request.getRequestURI()).forword(request,response);
```